# How to configure SNS delivery status with the AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

If you create an SNS Topic and, in the Amazon Console, open the `Delivery Status` options under `Other topic actions`, you can see this:

[image: SNS Topic Delivery Status]

As you can see, it's possible now to get SNS delivery status feedback by configuring success and failure IAM roles. This works fine and I can see all the logs in CloudWatch for all published messages to each subscriber.

What I **can't** do is to set these values with the `Java AWS SDK`, is there any way of doing this?

I'm using `aws-java-sdk:1.10.23` (latest as of now)

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/msg-status-topics.html#msg-status-sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @david-murray pointed out in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/msg-status-topics.html#msg-status-sdk), this is the solution to configure the feedback for HTTP endpoints:

```
amazonSnsClient.setTopicAttributes(topicArn, "HTTPFailureFeedbackRoleArn", "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/SNSFailureFeedback");
```

The same idea can be used for `Application`, `Lambda` and `SQS`.

My mistake was trying to set all of them with a single call like the form in the screenshot does by using:

`https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/SetMultiTopicAttributes`

Although this doesn't seem to be present in the SDK at the moment, 4 separate calls will have the same effect.

Thanks!